# How to allow all clients access to remote MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, firewall, root

So I followed [this guide](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/allow-mysql-client-connection/) to gain remote access to a MySQL server for my laptop.  However, my IP changes and I want to be able to access the  server outside my network.  How can I allow any client IP to access it if they have the password?

Here are the main commands that I'm referring to:

```
mysql> use mysql
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'client.ip.goes.here' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password'; 
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: Hi. Allowing that kind of access to MySQL over the INET is not a good idea. Have you considered using a simple SSH tunnel or even better a VPN?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to allow all IPs? That could be potentially dangerous depending on the use case.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems in the past. My solution was to tunnel the MySQL connect through a SSH tunnel. It's quick & dirty but effective. Firstly, MySQL is bound to 127.0.0.1 using the my.cnf &

> bind-address    = 127.0.0.1

This means MySQL is no longer available in the net. It won't answer any more queries unless they come from the local host. After that I install & configure openssh. I won't discuss that here, everybody has his own ideas on what's best. Just make sure that SSH is available in your net segment (or wherever you need it). On the Client I start a SSH tunnel.

> MySQLClient:~# ssh -f -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 mysqluser@MySQLServer -N

Now MySQL is reachable over my client. Simply

> mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1

I use this quite a lot & it works.

Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password';

It's a bit ugly though to give full access just with a password. I would suggest you use [SSL keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ssl-connections.html) for root logins, if you really need full remote access.